# Selenium test stalls running Selenium Grid v1.0.8 on Ubuntu v10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, selenium-grid

Installed Selenium Grid on Ubuntu successfully
Launched the hub and a Firefox remote control successfully
Running a phpunit/selenium test:
   Firefox starts up but the Selenium Remote Control times out and
errs with the following output:

ERROR – Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and
clear all session data
org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: timed out waiting
for window ‘null’ to appear

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by replacing the selenium-server-1.0.3-standalone.jar
file in /opt/selenium-grid-1.0.8/vendor with the current selenium
standalone jar (selenium-server-standalone-2.19.0.jar).
Be sure to remove or rename the old jar file, the remote controls use
the jar that matches selenium-server-*.jar.